# LAN working, TCP connects OK, but Mac AFP connects fail

Tags: mac, networking, afp

My LAN appears fine from a TCP/IP point of view over wifi: Macs on the wifi network are pingable, I can do web sharing and http://10.0.5.nn works fine. Internet access is also working for all machines.

However, I cannot connect via AFP: trying to see shared volumes on mymac.local results in a message to make sure sharing is on (it is) and to see my sysadmin if I still can't connect. That's me. It's a home network.

Don't know what to try next. Suggestion?

Thanks and regards,
David

**Update:**
Shutdown all computers on network, bounced the router/ DHCP server, then brought them up one at a time. Problem still there, but now I see it's a performance problem of some sort. Some attempts to connect to a share failed as before, but some succeeded after a Loooong time. Even after the share came up, copying a file to it was very slow. What the heck is going on???

Answer (score 0):

When you ping are you pinging by ip or by hostname(mymac.local)? If it is by ip then try connecting with afp://10.0.5.nn/shareName/.

Comment: pinging by ip. tried afp://10.0.5.nn/shareName/, same result: connection failed

Comment: Try connecting on the machine with the share. IE connect to itself using both ip and hostname.